# Is there a way to represent the set containing all possible proper sets of a large set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this question given:
Let set U = {n | n ∈ whole numbers, 10≤≤30 }; 
set B = {b | b ∈ even numbers};
set C = {c | c ∈ natural numbers, >10 and <30};
B ⊆ C;
C ⊆ U.
Answer all the following questions:
a. Write down all the possible proper subsets for C.

this question would bring a huge answer:
(2^19)-1 = 524287 
as you can see the solution to this question would be very large and nearly impossible to write in a mere paper, so I am looking for another way to represent the answer. 
my approach to the answer is: 
{{},{11},{12},...,{29},{11,12}, {11, 13},...,{28,29},{11,12,13},...,{27,28,29},{11,12,13,14},...,{12,13,...,29}}
of course this is inefficient and misses alot of information, therefore I am looking for another way to represent this large solution, possibly using set-builer notation

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: can you not just write $\mathcal{P}(C)\setminus\{C\}$?

Comment: The question asks to write down all possible proper subsets for C.

Comment: I think you're definitely not asked to write down all $524287$ proper subsets of $C$. Rather I guess you should describe them like $B$ is such a subset if and only if $B$ only contains integers between $11$ and $29$ (inclusive) but not all them.

Comment: How do I approach it in this method @Berci ?

Comment: Use your words. (Or mine.) Maybe ask your teacher what they would expect..